# react-native-chart-kit doesn't work in development mode, only in expo go

Tags: ios, expo, react-native-chart-kit

"requireNativeComponent: "RNSVGRect" was not found in the UIManager" is the error message i get when trying to view my Charts in The IOS Simulator.

I use an expo managed project. Already looked to posts with the similar problem but no solution was for expo.

Does anyone have an idea what else could be the problem.

```
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSVGPath" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
    in RNSVGPath (created by Path)
    in Path (created by PieChart)
    in RNSVGGroup (created by G)
    in G (created by PieChart)
    in RNSVGGroup (created by G)
    in G (created by PieChart)
    in RNSVGGroup (created by G)
    in G (created by Svg)
    in RNSVGSvgView (created by Svg)
    in Svg (created by PieChart)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by PieChart)
    in PieChart (created by Chart3)
    in Chart3 (created by Charts)
```

I have react-native-svg installed and the most recent version of react-native-chart-kit

tried rebuilding and dragging build into simulator.
tried uninstalling both libraries and installing them again